# Pointers and Dynamically Allocating Arrays error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I am getting an introduction to pointers and I don't understand the following code.

```
int main(){
        int *p;
        p=new int[5];
        cout << p <<endl;  // line 4
        *p=3;
        p=p+1;
        cout <<p <<endl;  // line 7
        *p=7;
        cout << p[0] <<endl;
    }
```

line 4 and line 7 prints the memory location as 0xd91730 and 0xd91734 respectively and I understand that. However, why is the last line `( p[0] )  printing 7 on the screen. Isn't p[0] = 3 instead, as assigned in line 5. I am not understanding this concept. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: One general thing you can do to help you understand code like this is to run it in your debugger. Running in your debugger is a skill that I unfortunately was not taught until graduate school, and I wish I had learned it sooner. It's easy, and it allows you to view the contents of all of your variables in real time as you step through the program line-by-line. Using your debugger you'd be able to see how the value of `p` changes at each line, and how the data stored in each index of `p` changes as well. If you need help running your debugger either search online or ask here!

Comment: @JohnFilleau Thanks, how do I use the debugger? I use CodeBlocks to write my program.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have experience with Code Blocks, but this wiki doesn't seem *too* bad? The main things you want to be able to do are "set a breakpoint" - this tells your debugger that you want execution to stop at THIS line. Then, once the code is stopped, you want to "step" through your code. This will move it to the next line. You can generally "step over" or "step into" when the next line is a function call. One just runs the function and stops at the next line after the function call. The other moves into the function. While stopped you can view the values of your variables.

Comment: Oops forgot the link: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: you moved pointer ahead by executing p = p + 1;
Forget about the address where p was pointing, now it points ahead by 4 bytes. Now you set the value at this new address to 7. p[0] will give you the value at this new address

Answer (score 2):

It actually does:

`p = new int[5]` which is fine. You allocated 5 integers worth of memory.
At `p[0]` you have stored the value 3 (`*p = 3`)..

You then **offset the pointer** `p` by 1 (`p = p + 1`).. and now you wrote `*p = 7`.. Of course printing `P[0]` is going to print 7 because you've offset p from its original position when you did `p = p + 1` (P no longer points to the same memory address you had when you did `new int[5]`).

You never decreased the pointer back to point to 3.

If you did `delete[] p` after increasing it, it'd be undefined behaviour and possibly crash on you because you are deleting memory location since you increased P.

If you wanted it to print 3, you'd have to do `P = P - 1` after writing 7 to P[1].

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with pointers the square bracket notation is just way of dereferencing a pointer.

```
p[x]   is syntactically equivalent to   *(p + x)
```

So you are de-referencing the memory location x points ahead of the pointer.

In your code. After you have allocated memory you move the pointer:

```
    p = p+1;   // This moves p to point at the next location in memory.
```

Now your memory looks like this:

```
Memory      0xd91730        [0, 0, 0 ,3]   => 4 bytes 
p --------->0xd91734        [0, 0, 0, 7]   => 4 bytes (yes I am making an assumption 
            0xd91738        [?, ?, ?, ?]               about layout for demonstrating
            0xd9173c        [?, ?, ?, ?]               purposes)
```

De-referencing p will give you the content at `0xs91734`.

Try adding the following line:

```
            std::cout << p[-1] << "\n"; // Should return the 3 you were looking for
```

Just for fun try:

```
            std::cout << 0[p] << "\n";  // Blows your mind but works.

            // Pointer + integer is a pointer.
            // integer + Pointer is also a pointer.
            // So 0[p] => *(0 + p) => *(p + 0) => p[0]
```